# How can I get texture file by using assimp?

Tags: 3d, fbx, assimp

I am developing FBX model viewer using directx and assimp library. For loading texture, I called function like below. (I got FBX from mixamo)

```
aiString path;
mat->Get(AI_MATKEY_TEXTURE_DIFFUSE(0), path); // mat is aiMaterial*
```

The "path" variable now has "**../../../../home/app/mixamo-mini/tmp/skins_XXX.fbm/Mutant_Diffuse.png**"

I cannot find that path on my computer from the location where FBX file exists. I use Windows 11 Pro. How can I read the texture files Assimp extracted ? Even "../../../../home" does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an Asspmp-Problem because the library will just read the texture information provided by your model.

This is a relative path description which was written by the Modeller when writing the model onto disk. The referenced texture was located at **../../../../home/app/mixamo-mini/tmp/skins_XXX.fbm/**.

I guess you need to look for the textures by yourself and adapt the path description for the texture by yourself.